# Concurrent code (GCD)

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, watchkit

Sorry my english is bad.

I have a question about Grand Central Dispatch implementation.

I want to implement a slide show of photographs.

Imagine you have a list of urls to download photos from the cloud and show it.
My idea is to write the following concurrent code:

1) Download a fist photo

2) Show the picture and parallel start downloading the second

3) Wait 4 seconds or wait to download the photo (which last longer)

4) Go back to step 2

How I implement this in GCD?

Should I use Groups?

Comment: Check Apple docs or some standard examples. You can do it multiple ways as far as it serves your need. You can either use GCD or NSOperationQueue. I prefer to use NSOperationQueue where we have more command to deal with things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

- It will remove your overhead of managing multithreading.
- It is providing Asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an UIImageView category.
- It provides track image download progress as well.

See [Here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: I use my code in a WatchKit extension. I don't have a UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be if using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Use `UIImageView+AFNetworking` ,once `image` `downloaded` with a `url` gets `cached` using `AFImageCache` (NSCache).

If you by chance use `same url` to `download` `image` but it will `not` opt for `download` but provide you `cached` `image`.

Take a look at this category of imageView `UIImageView+AFNetworking's setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`

Comment: I use my code in a WatchKit extension. I don't have a UIImageView

Comment: have you mentioned anywhere that you want solution for WatchKit??? Should we assume our self what you want??

Comment: Prince, I clearly asked for help with GCD (because it is compatible with watchkit)